# Flex: select count( id ) returns the result in strange way with SQLStatement?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

When i execute a query with Flex which contain some expression like "select count(id) as idCount from users" the result is coming in some strange way.

The 1st object from the result data array ( which is supposed to store the actual result from the query above ) having the follow "idCount = 0"
if i try to parse it as property - the result is always "undefined"

```
sqlStatement               = new SQLStatement();
sqlStatement.sqlConnection = mainConnection;
sqlStatement.text          = 'select count( id ) as countID from Users';
sqlStatement.addEventListener( SQLEvent.RESULT, onSelectQuerySucceed );
sqlStatement.execute();


protected function onSelectQuerySucceed( event : SQLEvent ) : void
{
    var sqlResult : SQLResult = sqlStatement.getResult();
    Alert.show( sqlResult.data[ 0 ].idCount ); // <- it is undefined :|
}
```

- How to properly execute such query and check the result ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?  Are you using the ActionScript SQLLite APIs?  If not; how are you executing the query?

Comment: i have added the code i am executing. i hope it does help in solving the issue :|

Comment: solved it. bah... this was lame from my side... the code working fine. i just miss a bit in other procedure. anyway Flextras - you made me think about why this is not working, while it seems perfectly fine :| Thanks man. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above working fine :|
Seems like it was my mistake in other procedure which causing the bug. :|

Comment: at least i hope the code help someone else looking for some solution of sort.